# How can I wait for all Kubernetes pods to be 2/2 and status to be in running stage?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I am writing a shell script in which I need to wait for all the pods to be in 2/2 and be in running stage before proceeding further. There are around seven pods in the namespace. How can I achieve this?

I have tried to run a `while` loop by checking if each pod is in running state and 2/2 using this:

```bash
kubectl get pods -n iit-oratst15 | grep 'Running' | awk 'NR >= 1 && NR < 2{print $2}'
```

but it seems to be not the best idea.

I am expecting for my script to wait until all the pods are in 2/2 and running stage before proceeding further.

Comment: One of the option would be curling health url of second container and relying on success state

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `kubectl wait` command.

If all of your pods can be identified by a particular label, you can do something like this (assuming your pods have label `app` equal to `example`):

```
kubectl wait --for condition=ready pod -l app=example
```

If you want to wait for all pods regardless of label, you can run:

```
kubectl wait --for condition=ready $(kubectl get pod -o name)
```

That second `kubectl` command (`kubectl get pod -o name`) produces a list of pods like:

```
pod/name_of_pod1
pod/name_pof_pod2
.
.
.
```

That provides appropriate arguments to the `kubectl wait` command.